# funcionamiento de un cron en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, cron

utilizo la librería [cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) para ejecutar el siguiente fragmento de código

```
pepinosModelo.find()
  .exec()
  .then(pepinos => {

    pepinos.forEach(pepino => {

      let frecuencia = pepino.frecuente();
      let nuevoTrans = [{
        chocolate:true,
        abena:"de dos a tres porcines",
        lsd: "No aplica"
      }];


      nuevoTrans.push({
        chocolate:false,
        coco:"Completo",
        lsd: "Aplica"
      });

      return TransModel.create(nuevoTrans)
      .then((trans) => {

        fumadorModelo
        .update({
          pepino: pepino._id
        }, { 
          'comprador': false,
          'nuevaDocis': zero 
        })
        .exec()
        .then((usuario) => { 
          pepino.cambio += frecuencia;
          pepino.balance = zero;
          pepino.puntos = zero;
          return pepino
          .save()
          .then(() => {
            console.log(´fin actualizacion usuario ciclo ${usuario}´);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

y para que se ejecute lo hago de esta forma

```
  try{
  // let when = '00 30 11 1-2 * *';
  // let timeZone = '';
  let when = '* 10 * * * *';

  new CronJob({
    cronTime: when,
    onTick: cronFn,
    start: true,
    // timeZone
  });

}catch(err) {
  console.error('something happening with cron:', err);
}
```

- La cuestión es que no estoy tan seguro si ejecuta varias veces la tarea o solo una vez
- ¿Esto podría saturar el servidor dependiendo de la cantidad de documentos en la colección pepino?
- Que pasa si falla en la actualización o creación de un documento

Answer (score 0):

Según tu cron pattern corre cada 30 minutos.

- Si querés saber cuantas veces corre, agrega logs y verificalos.
- No se que estas usando para traer tus documentos, pero te recomiendo hacerño páginado para que no rompa, ya que si traes 1 millon de registros lo mas probable es que pase dependiendo del servidor
- Si falla la actualización o creación deberia tirarte un warning por consola ya que por lo que veo no estas usando ningun catch

1.) Primero te recomiendo que traigas el contenido páginado

2.) Te Crees una función aparte con Promise que haga la creación y el update y una vez que termine haga el resolve.

3.) Luego te recomiendo que tu for solo haga los inserts en nuevoTrans con la promesa de esa función.

4.) Con esa lista hagas un Promise.all

Me parecería mucho mas prolijo y mas alineado a ES6